# GPS Delegate Sending Information to CCLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, gps

I am currently trying to use a GPS delegate to get the user's GPS location and send that information to a CCLayer from Cocos2d. The idea is to display the GPS coordinates on screen using a CCLabelTTF. I would also like to be able to use the schedule function on a CCLayer to update the location.

The reason I have resorted to asking this question is because all of the tutorials I have found create a UIViewController integrated with the GPS manager, which does not fit what I have in mind.

No code to show here because anything I have created has become a jumbled mess.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with CCLayer etc. However, getting GPS updates, isn't that simply:

1. Instantiating a CLLocationManager object
2. Setting the manager's delegate to your own object where you handle GPS updates. I.e., you will have to implement the 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' protocol.
3. At least implement the locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method (you may need more).

Perhaps I missed the essence of your question?